# jquery draggable fire event if dragging for more than X seconds

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a group os sortable elements and a hidden droppable wich is the trash to remove elements and I'm showing the trash when dragging starts, that's ok. 
What I want is to show the trash only if I'm dragging an element for more than a given number of seconds.
How can I achieve this?

right now my code for this is

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
   start: function (event, ui) { $("#trash").slideDown(); },
   stop: function (event, ui) { $("#trash").slideUp(); }
});
$(".sortable").disableSelection();

$("#trash").droppable({
  drop: function (event, ui) { $(ui.draggable).remove(); }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delay the slideDown using a `setTimeout` and clear the timeout in the stop event; in this case it's important to set [`refreshPositions`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-refreshPositions) (inherited from draggable) option to true in you sortable because the DOM change during dragging and this change must be notified to the draggable.

A note from the docs:

> If set to true, all droppable positions are calculated on every
>   mousemove. Caution: This solves issues on highly dynamic pages, but
>   dramatically decreases performance.

Code:

```
var delayOpen;

$("#sortable").sortable({
    start: function (event, ui) {
        delayOpen = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#trash").slideDown();
            $("#sortable").sortable("refresh");
        }, 1000);
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        clearTimeout(delayOpen)
        $("#trash").slideUp();
    },
    refreshPositions: true
});
$("#sortable").disableSelection();

$("#trash").droppable({
    over: function (event, ui) {
        console.log('overd')
    },
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).remove();
    }
}).hide();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/7pkRS/

Comment: this is great, exactlu what i wanted. there's something else the draggable element is only considered over the droppable when its center is over it, is there any way to make it considered to be over even if only one tip of the element is over the droppable? Should i post a new question for this?

Comment: nevermind the last comment i found the option for this. just have to set tolerance: "touch" in the droppable